# tcl command to search for a particular word inside a txt file in linux

Tags: linux, tcl

I need to write a tcl script that will process the lines of a text file.  The file is looks like

```
10.77.33.247    10.77.33.241        rtp 0x26
10.77.33.247    10.77.33.241        rtp 0x26
10.77.33.247    10.77.33.241        rtp 0x26
10.77.33.247    10.77.33.241            0x24
10.77.33.247    10.77.33.241            0x22
10.77.33.247    10.77.33.241            0x21
```

I need to be able to iterate through the file and for each line that contains `rtp` store the value that comes after it (e.g., `0x26` in the sample above) in a variable to do use in other parts of the script.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a (rather low-level) Tcl way to do it.

```
set ch [open myfile.txt]
set data [chan read $ch]
chan close $ch

set lines [split [string trim $data] \n]

set res {}
foreach line $lines {
    if {[llength $line] > 3 && [lindex $line 2] eq {rtp}} {
        lappend res [lindex $line 3]
    }
}
```

If you replace "myfile.txt" with the name of your data file and run this code, you get the words you were after collected in the variable `res`.

---

#### Explanation

It's usually best to use standard (builtin or tcllib) commands, such as `fileutil::foreachLine` in glenn jackman's answer. If one wants to do it step by step, however, Tcl still makes it very easy.

The first step is to get the contents of the file into memory. There is a standard command for that too: `fileutil::cat`, but the following sequence will do:

```
set ch [open myfile.txt]
set data [chan read $ch]
chan close $ch
```

(This is more or less equivalent to `set data [fileutil::cat myfile.txt]`.)

Next step is to split the text into lines. It's always a good idea to trim off whitespace at both ends of the text, otherwise loose newlines can create empty elements that disturb processing.

```
set lines [split [string trim $data] \n]
```

In some cases, we might have to split the lines into lists of fields, but from the example it seems that the lines are already usable as lists (lines that only have whitespace, alphanumerics, and well-behaved punctuation such as dots usually are).

We need a test for matching lines. There are several alternatives that fit the example data you provided, including

```
string match *rtp* $line  ;# match every line that has "rtp" somewhere
[llength $line] > 3       ;# match every line that has more than three columns
[lindex $line 2] eq {rtp} ;# match every line where the third element is "rtp"
```

We also need a way to extract the data we want. If the word after "rtp" is always in the last column, `[lindex $line end]` will do the job. If the word is always in the fourth column, but there may be further columns, `[lindex $line 3]` is better.

Grabbing a couple of these alternatives, the procedure to get a list of words as specified can be written

```
set res {}
foreach line $lines {
    if {[llength $line] > 3 && [lindex $line 2] eq {rtp}} {
        lappend res [lindex $line 3]
    }
}
```

(In pseudo-code: get an empty list (`res`); test every line (using a combination of two of the tests above), extract the sought-after word from every matching line and add it to the `res` list.)

or, using `lmap` (Tcl 8.6+)

```
set res [lmap line $lines {
    if {[llength $line] > 3 && [lindex $line 2] eq {rtp}} {
        lindex $line 3
    } else {
        continue
    }
}]
```

All the words that came after a "rtp" word should now be in `res`. If you just wanted the last match, it's `[lindex $res end]`.

Documentation: [chan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.htm), [continue](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/continue.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [llength](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/llength.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: can you please post the exact piece of code once again here, so that i can be assure of what i understood

Comment: @user3388407: take a look at my answer. The first piece of code is the whole procedure (I've added a line to it to separate it from the rest of the answer). The other bits of code in the answer are pieces of that procedure explained. There is not point in posting it again, because it's already there.

Comment: peter one more thing, i want this code in unix, the first top code which you have written, when i am trying to execute it in unix it is showing as invalid command "chan"  , can i get some equvalent code in unix

Comment: @user3388407: it's not a platform issue, it's a version issue. The chan command was added in Tcl 8.5: you're probably using Tcl 8.4 or earlier. 8.4 isn't supported anymore, and you should upgrade. If you can't upgrade, simply 1) remove the word "chan" (keep "read" and "close") and 2) change "eq" to "==", and the code should work in Tcl 8.4.

Comment: Thanks peter...it woked

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your file is foo.txt:

```
grep "word" foo.txt
```

Comment: suppose first i open the file and then read it one by one, the problem is 0x26 is dynamic it will change , so basically i want the value which is after rtp in the same line

Answer (score 0):

grep "0x26" file.txt
will show you all the lines with 0x26 in them.

Comment: "0x26" is not static , it will change everytime, i need the value which is after rtp in the same line

Answer (score 0):

[tcllib](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/home) has lots of goodness in it:

```
% package require fileutil
1.14.5
% fileutil::foreachLine line "file" {
    if {[string match {*rtp*} $line]} {
        lappend values [lindex [split $line] end]
    }
}
% puts $values
0x26 0x26 0x26
```

Comment: i am not able to understand the code ....can you please write it exactly what needs to be written.....please i need it urgently

Comment: i didn't get your above code could you please clarify a bit, please suggest the code which i can use for getting the exact value

Comment: If you need it urgently, take [Peter's code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30080117/7552)

Comment: will that code works in tcl, do i need to do any modification there or is it fine,

Comment: please suggest because currently i dont have the system to execute it, but i need it working after an hour

Comment: set ch [open myfile.txt] ==> in this command in place of myfile.txt i need to provide the exact path of my file?.    can you please provide one complete piece of code here, i am in a bit of urgency

Comment: @user3388407: yes, replace `myfile.txt` with your path. The first code example in my answer is complete and working. Please comment on my answer instead of here if you want to discuss my answer.

Comment: @user3388407, this is not a code-for-hire site. We have expectations on you, the asker, to do most of the actual work.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for getting the text from the file which is in cotes (" "):

```html
proc aifWebcamInitVideo {} { 
 
 variable devicePath "c:/testfile.txt"

 #ffmpeg command to get the device name connected to system
 exec ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy >& $devicePath &
 
 after 4000                                                                                                   ;# wait of 4 seconds so that device can be selected.
 set files [glob $aif::LogRootDir/*]                                                                          ;# Look for all the files.
 foreach file $files {
 set fileName $devicePath
  if {[string match $fileName $file ] } {                                                                  ;# this if statement check currently captured video with the files present in directory.
   set file [open $devicePath ]                                                                         ;# open the file
   set file_device [read  $file]
   set data [split $file_device "\n"]                                                                   ;# divides the open file into lines.
   foreach line $data {                                                      
    if {[regexp {"([^""]*)"} $line -> substring]} {                                                  ;# check for the quotes to retrieve the device connected to system.
     set result $substring
     lappend cameraList $result                                                                   ;# makes the list of devices.
     set camera [lindex $cameraList 0]
    }
   }
   close $file
   break
  } 
 }
 
 #values passed to FFMPEG command.
 
 variable TableCamera $camera
 puts "Device selected for Video capture is : $TableCamera"                                     ;# gets the first device from the list
}
```